# SDL Web 8 installation Files/Folders missing

Tags: web8

I have a requirement to install Web8 core then update it to web8.1.1
The directory structure of Web 8 installation media does not match with the 
[SDL web 8 insallation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DMTS&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1462803197055&currentQuery=MTS&currentScope=)

In SDL Documentation there should be a  setenv.ps1,quickinstall.ps1 and some configuration files in Content Delivery\resources\quickinstall\

path and session microservice in Content Delivery\roles\ folder which are missing

If anyone can help me out to either get the missing files/Folder or provide me documentation tosetup Web 8 Core

Comment: As Vinay suggests, you probably have the Web 8 GA (8.1) release media instead of 8.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`quickinstall` scripts and `session` roles were introduced in 8.1.1 and hence it will not be present in CD 8.1.0.

Prior to 8.1.1, we didn't have scripts for quick installation and for session role, there were documentation steps to update content role to act as session enabled content service.

Comment: Can you please share the url which has steps for Settingup Content Delivery for sdl web 8.0. The only documentation i can find is below and it ask to execute quickinstall script which is not present in th sdl web 8.0 installation setup folder, how to proceed now in this case http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB